# Find formula: 4 variables but I have all the data

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is this boardgame called [Monopoly Stock Exchange](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/3065/monopoly-stock-exchange). In this game you use a "computer" to keep track of your proceedings, calculates the rent etc. Just out of curiosity, I want to know the inner workings of the machine. Since I know all variables and the outcome is not random, there must be a way to determine a formula out of this. How do I do this?

The variables:

- A: the "base-value" of the property (between 60 and 400)
- B: the number of players owning stock (between 1 and 6)
- C: the number of shares sold (between 1 and 9)
- D: the number of buildings on the property (between 0 and 5)
- E: the fact that I have a monopoly (own all properties of the same colour)

For example, the most easy example:

- A=60, B=1, C=1, D=0, E=no, then the outcome would be 7

Since I own the game and therefore have the computer at my disposal, I can generate ALL the numbers that I like. So that is what I did, I sat down and started writing down the numbers: entered them in sheets, plot them into graphs, subtracted numbers, multiplied, etc... but I cannot find a formula to predict them!

Some more numbers:

- A=60, B=3, D=1, D=0, E=yes, then the outcome would be 18
- A=180, B=6, C=4, D=0, E=no, then the outcome would be 55
- A=260, B=5, C=2, D=0, E=no, then the outcome would be 62

And so on...

Is there a website where I can enter the values, and a function will pop-out? Can I simply use Excel to find this "magic formula"? How do I start?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There may not be a simple formula.  Why should there be?  That said, what you might is hold four of the variables constant, and let the fifth vary, and see if there is a simple formula in that case.  Then you can change the values of one of the four variables and try again.  It may be a long process, with no certainty of success.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi @saulspatz , thanks for your reply! Why should there be a formula, you ask. Well, I just cannot believe the creators entered all these values by hand. Some values may be constants, and the values follow some kind of pattern. They might be based on values from the original game?
But it just intrigues me, and I keep wondering what the best way would be to determine a formula from a known set of values. There has to be a way to do such a thing, right?

Comment: That's a fair point.  Have you tried the procedure I suggested?

Comment: I've created a simple program to display all the results (loaded from input tables), after calculating them with my formula. I can now tweak the formula and the results are immediately displayed in a large table (green for ok, red for not ok). So it's back to trial and error now...

Comment: OK, I really think I have found my formula! Lot's of trial and error, but with enough data it came clear I was on the right track. Thanks for your input!